# Decimal expansion of a rational number

Tags: java, mathematics, rational-numbers, fixed-point

I wrote a program that does division and either does or doesn't show repeating groups. After designing it the first time I had to redesign it because although it worked it was unnecessarily complex. And now I am presenting to you my refined division program, for feedback and improvement ideas:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Division
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(/)(\\d+)");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a fraction in the form x/y: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        while(!m.matches())
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a fraction in the form x/y: ");
            input = in.nextLine();
            m = p.matcher(input);
        }
        in.close();

        int top = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int bottom = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        System.out.println("Result: " + divide(top,bottom,true));
    }

    public static String divide(int numerator, int denominator, boolean showRepeatingGroup)
    {
        int whole = (int)numerator / denominator;
        numerator = (numerator - (whole * denominator)) * 10;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(whole + ".");
        Set<Integer> remainders = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

        while(remainders.add(numerator))
        {
            whole = (int)numerator / denominator;
            result.append(whole);
            numerator = (numerator - (whole * denominator)) * 10;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> remaindersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(remainders);
        if (result.charAt(result.length() - 1) != '0' && showRepeatingGroup)
        {
            int position = remaindersList.indexOf(numerator) + 2;
            result.insert(position,  "{");
            result.append("}");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program does not seem to work correctly. E.g. the input `1/7` produces the output `0.142{857}`. Correct would be `0.{142857}`.

Comment: `2/14` gives `0.14{2857}` even if it is the same value as `1/7`. – `1/90` gives `0.{01}` instead of `0.0{1}`.

Comment: @MartinR Showing repeating groups has given me so much trouble... I should just leave that out. It's so temperamental, sometimes it works and others it doesn't. `22/7` works and so does `7/22`

Comment: @MartinR Fixed it. Just learnt that `HashSet` doesn't add things in order. So I changed it to a `LinkedHashSet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The conversion

Your program does not produce the correct output in all cases.

- `10000/3` produces `33{33.3}` instead of `3333.{3}`.

  The reason is that in

  ```
  int position = remaindersList.indexOf(numerator) + 2;
  ```

  you assume that the integer part of the fraction is exactly one digit.
  This can be (e.g.) solved by remembering the string length right after the integer part has been build:

  ```
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(whole + ".");
  int initialLength = result.length();
  ```
- `120/999` produces `0.120` instead of `0.{120}`

  The reason is that in

  ```
  if (result.charAt(result.length() - 1) != '0' && showRepeatingGroup)
  ```

  the last fraction digit is checked as indicator if the fraction is
  repeating or not. This does not work, you have to check if 
  `numerator` becomes zero.
- `2/5` produces `0.40` instead of `0.4`

  The reason is that you only check for a repeating remainder, but not
  if the numerator becomes zero. Therefore an additional `0` is appended
  to all non-repeating fractions.

Instead of a (ordered) hash set for the reminders which is converted
to a list later, I would use an (array) list in the first place.
Then you can check for repeating remainders *and* remember the position
to insert the group markers at the right place.

Other small things: The cast in

```
int whole = (int)numerator / denominator;
```

is not necessary, and

```
numerator = (numerator - (whole * denominator)) * 10;
```

can be simplified to

```
numerator = (numerator % denominator) * 10;
```

Taking all this into account, the `divide()` function becomes

```
public static String divide(int numerator, int denominator, boolean showRepeatingGroup)
{
    int whole = numerator / denominator;
    numerator = (numerator % denominator) * 10;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(whole + ".");
    int initialLength = result.length();

    List<Integer> remainders = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int repeatingPos = -1;

    while (numerator > 0 && repeatingPos == -1) {
        remainders.add(numerator);
        whole = numerator / denominator;
        numerator = (numerator % denominator) * 10;
        result.append(whole);
        repeatingPos = remainders.indexOf(numerator);
    }

    if (repeatingPos >= 0 && showRepeatingGroup) {
        result.insert(initialLength + repeatingPos,  "{");
        result.append("}");
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

But what I don't like is that the calculation of the fractional digits
is mixed with the conversion to a string. If we define a dedicated
`DecimalFraction` class then the two tasks can be separated clearly:

```
class DecimalFraction {
    int wholePart;      // Integer part
    List<Integer> fractionDigits; // Fractional digits
    int repeatingAt;    // Position of first repeating digit, or (-1)

    DecimalFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        wholePart = numerator / denominator;
        numerator = (numerator % denominator) * 10;
        fractionDigits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        repeatingAt = -1;

        List<Integer> remainders = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (numerator > 0 && repeatingAt == -1) {
            remainders.add(numerator);
            int whole = numerator / denominator;
            numerator = (numerator % denominator) * 10;
            fractionDigits.add(whole);
            repeatingAt = remainders.indexOf(numerator);
        }
    }

    String toString(boolean showRepeatingGroup) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(wholePart + ".");
        for (int i = 0; i < fractionDigits.size(); i++) {
            if (showRepeatingGroup && i == repeatingAt) {
                result.append("{");
            }
            result.append(fractionDigits.get(i));
        }
        if (showRepeatingGroup && repeatingAt >= 0) {
            result.append("}");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This can now be used as

```
DecimalFraction dfrac = new DecimalFraction(numerator, denominator);
System.out.println("Result: " + dfrac.toString(true));
```

### The main program

As already mentioned in a comment, the slash does not need a pattern group:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
```

The code duplication in the "read until input is valid loop" can be
avoided by using a `do {  } while()` :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Matcher m;
do  {
    System.out.print("Enter a fraction in the form x/y: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    m = p.matcher(input);
} while (!m.matches());
in.close();
```

And finally, I don't see why the variables are called `top`/`bottom`
instead of `numerator`/`denominator`:

```
int numerator = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
int denominator = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));

DecimalFraction dfrac = new DecimalFraction(numerator, denominator);
System.out.println("Result: " + dfrac.toString(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good overall. Some general, small changes I could mention:

- Some useless parenthesis.

  ```
  numerator = (numerator - (whole * denominator)) * 10;
  ```

  ```
  numerator = (numerator - whole * denominator) * 10;
  ```
- ArrayList uses the List Interface, so you can change

  `ArrayList<Integer> remaindersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(remainders);`

  `List<Integer> remaindersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(remainders);`
- Use packages. Even just for personal stuff. I usually do com.thisismyusername.project